# Compiling Code for Gnome Keyrings

Tags: c, gcc, gnome

I've found a sample about using Gnome Keyrings, but I'm unable to compile it, I don't know the required includes or libraries, and I can't seem to find this info in the documentation, so any help would be really appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>

/* A callback called when operation completes */
static void stored_password (GnomeKeyringResult res, gpointer user_data)
{
        /* user_data will be the same as was passed to gnome_keyring_store_password() */
        if (res == GNOME_KEYRING_RESULT_OK)
                g_print ("password saved successfully!\n");
        else
                g_print ("couldn't save password: %s", gnome_keyring_result_to_message (res));
}

static void save_my_password()
{
        gnome_keyring_store_password (GNOME_KEYRING_NETWORK_PASSWORD, /* The password type */
                                      GNOME_KEYRING_DEFAULT,          /* Where to save it */
                                      _("My special password"),       /* Password description, displayed to user */
                                      "the-password",                 /* The password itself */
                                      stored_password,                /* A function called when complete */
                                      NULL, NULL,                     /* User data for callback, and destroy notify */

                                      /* These are the attributes */
                                      "user", "me", 
                                      "server", "gnome.org",

                                      NULL); /* Always end with NULL */
}

int main()
{
    save_my_password();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) and shell expansion to automatically get the required dependencies:

```
gcc -o test test.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gnome-keyring-1 gtk+-2.0)
```

Also, instead of including `gtkmm.h` header include plain `gtk+.h`:

```
-#include <gtkmm.h>
+#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

[Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org) is C++ interface and if you are coding in plain C, you don't really need it.

Now when I'm looking at your `main` function, I have to say that your approach is almost right, but it won't work because in order to run gtk+ apps (show widgets like error dialogs), you need to do some initialization first (ie. start the main loop). Check out the [Typical main() function for Gtk+ application example](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html) in the description.

Comment: it cant find gtkmm.h or gtk/gtk.h, "error: gtkmm.h No such file or directory"

Comment: sorry, gtk/gtk.h and not gtkmm

Comment: Ah, yes, you need to add `gtk+-2.0` to the `pkg-config` list.